# I got error while building package plutus-core-0.1.0.0 when installing cardano-wallet using stack

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, cabal, macos

I'm using MacOS Monterey with M1 chip and trying to install `cardano-wallet`. I've already installed pre-requisites `cardano-node` and `cardano-cli` no problem, and already synced with the testnet.

I was following this guide
https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-wallet

At step `$ stack build --test --no-run-tests`, I got the following error happening at 443/460

[image]

This is after I tried running `$ stack build --test --no-run-tests` again right after

[image]

Can somebody help me?

Comment: I'm not a Mac guy but the error looks like a mismatch between x86 and ARM arch code. Maybe look more into using Rosetta (Intel emulation).
This might help too: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/installing-cardano-node-on-an-m1-mac

Comment: Did you build `cardano-node` or download the binary?

Comment: @MC_Brisbane Thanks, but I will try to follow the Github guide first on cardano-wallet repo itself, since the Cardano Developer website seems outdated. 

I built the cardano-node from the source using cabal, didn't download the binary

Comment: Ok good, since you built the node from source that is a good sign that your env is/was working ok without fundamental issues.